# Read xlsx file and convert into xml using xslt

Tags: xslt

Can anyone help me out in reading the content of a simple excel xlsx file using xslt to convert it into xml.
A simple program in helping me understand the procedure will be of great help.

For Example:
I have movie 1(Cell A1) title 1(Cell B) and movie 2(Cell A2) and title 2(Cell B2) in my excel file
How will I be able to read the data using xslt?

Comment: I am afraid you are asking the wrong question. An .xlsx file is a ZIP archive containing a collection of XML (and other) files - one of which contains the data you are looking for. So your real question should be about opening the archive and locating the correct file. Only then you can begin an XSLT transformation into another XML schema.

Comment: Yes exactly...So how would i be able to do that ?

Comment: I don't know. You can't do this with XSLT. You *can* do this with any number of other tools.